# Initial value of <select> with using "Controller as" and this instead of $scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a select

```
 <select ng-model="artistOrder">
                <option value="name">Name</option>
                <option value="reknown">Reknown</option>
 </select>
```

I want to set a initial value of this select, so I set it in my controller

```
app.controller('artistCtrl', ['$http', function ($http) {
var store = this;
store.artistList = [];
$http.get('js/data.json').success(function (data) {
    store.artistList = data;
});
store.artistOrder = 'name';
}]);
```

However, `store.artistOrder = 'name'` does not work. If I use $scope implementation, it will work with `$scope.artistOrder = 'name'`

Comment: `store.artistOrder = 'name'` --> for this you syntax as `MyController as Ctrl` then `Ctrl.artistOrder`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, if I use `Ctrl.artistOrder`, I got this error `angular.min.js:84 TypeError: Cannot set property 'artistOrder' of undefined`. I am kinda new to angularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check answer with comments.

```
<div ng-controller="artistCtrl as Ctrl"> <!-- this is what you should look for -->
    <select ng-model="Ctrl.artistOrder"> <!-- check how we are using it to get property set on instance -->
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="reknown">Reknown</option>
    </select>
</div>

app.controller('artistCtrl', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var store = this; // this is controller instance not scope
    store.artistList = [];
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function (data) {
        store.artistList = data;
    });
    store.artistOrder = 'name';
}]);
```

[ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)